# Python Error: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I got this error while programming a discord bot in python. Supposedly, client = discord.Client() causes this error. I dont know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
import discord
import random





client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I deleted the token for saftey resons.

Comment: That means you have to provide a keyword argument named `intents` to `Client()`.

Comment: Also, make sure you have 'Privileged Gateway Intents' enabled in the Discord Developer Portal.

Comment: how would i implement these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need `intents` when defining `Client`

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

In addition, you have to enable 'Privileged Gateway Intents' in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Also see [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Intents)